# Chrome menu hidden in full screen mode

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

Whenever I try to access the Chrome menu in full-screen mode, a small black panel appears, with no menu:[image]

However, when I'm not in full-screen mode, it works fine:[image]

Anyone know what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you add the black panel on the top right of the first image? Or has Chrome got a toast alert you can't see/hasn't rendered properly?

Comment: That black panel is what appears when I try and access the menu. I've explicitly edited my question to say this.

Comment: That looks like a hooky extension. Have you tried a factory reset of Chrome?